# String manipulation in R to create dataframe column

Tags: string, r

I have  an R dataframe(df) which includes a factor column, Team

```
Team
Baltimore Orioles
Kansas City Chiefs
...
```

I just want to create a new column, nickname, which just refers to the last name

```
Nickname
Orioles
Chiefs
```

As a first stage, I have tried splitting the factor like this

```
df$Nickname <- strsplit(as.character(df$Team), " ")
```

which produces a list of character fields which I  can reference thus

```
>df$Nickname[1]

[[1]]
[1] "Baltimore" "Orioles"
```

and

```
>str(df$Nickname[1])

List of 1
 $ : chr [1:2] "Baltimore" "Orioles"
```

but then I do not know how to proceed. Trying to get the length

> length(df$Nickname[1])

gives 1 - which flummoxes me

Comment: What about the Boston Red Sox?

Comment: Also, you probably wanted `length(df$Nickname[[1]])` or `sapply(df$Nickname, length)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to unlist the split strings and take the last one

```
    full <- c("Baltimore Orioles","Kansas City Chiefs")
    getlast <- function(x){
    parts <- unlist(strsplit(x, split = " "))
    parts[length(parts)]
    }
    sapply(full,getlast)
    > Baltimore Orioles Kansas City Chiefs 
    > "Orioles"           "Chiefs"
```

Comment: Nice, Tim.  A slightly simpler version might be `sapply(strsplit(full, split=" "), tail, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks Guys This forum is the only one where I can post a question, go brush my teeth, come back and find an answer.make a coffee and have an enhancement

Comment: Aaron - beautiful, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Use a regular expression:

```
text <- c("Baltimore Orioles","Kansas City Chiefs")

gsub("^.*\\s", "", text)
[1] "Orioles" "Chiefs"
```

The regex searches for:

- `^` means the start of the string
- `.*` means any character, repeated
- `\\s` means a single white space

`gsub` finds this pattern and replaces it with an empty string, leaving you with the last word of each string.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
require(plyr)
ldply(df$Nickname)
```